Find the Numbers 50-70 Using 2,0,2,4
I’ve been working on this paper I found online as a hobby. The numbers I’m trying to find are 56,59,63, and 77. Now my math is a bit rusty so the post I found didn’t really help me.
The rules of the paper are:
Only use the numbers 2,0,2,4 each only once.
You are allowed to used fractions, decimals, single and double factorials. As well as adding, subtracting, dividing, and multiplying.
I have seen the post such as 50-100 but I want to be able to understand the math so could someone please simplify it?
Link for the paper
https://mathequalslove.net/yearly-number-challenge/

I don’t understand the answers for that post so I’m looking for simplified answers since I want to be able I understand what I’m working on

I’m also a new user so I’m trying to understand if I’m not allowed to have a post similar to another one even though I have stated why I can’t use that one

Simplified just means that you can use factorial and double factorial because the ones with 5 of them don’t make sense to me. Another example is just problems that dont has 20 different symbols in them.

Hi guys just checking in has anyone found 77 yet I’m still struggling the closest I can get is 78 or 79. I was thinking maybe it’s not possible but I want to get others opinions before deciding that.

I think you should post the full rules here, and not just link to another site with a different target, because near the top of the linked page it says "You may use any mathematical symbol or operation of your choosing." But further down it contradicts itself with "I have seen some people use the floor and ceiling functions in this challenge, but I have never allowed my students or myself to do this."

I didn’t realize that i was told to link the actual paper by moderators so I did but I guess I didn’t notice the writing mistake.

I have some fairly simple expressions for all four numbers.
Only 77 uses a leading decimal point.

 $ 56 = (20 + 4!!) \times 2 $
$ 59 = ((0! + 4)! - 2) \ / \ 2 $
$ 63 = 2 ^ {2 + 4} - 0! $
$ 77 = .2 \times (0! + (2 \times 4)!!) $


Just in before me, I have a similar but slightly different method.

Thank you so much!

Here's a 56:

 $$\frac{(2 \times 4)!}{((2+0!)!)!} = \frac{8!}{((2+1)!)!} = \frac{8!}{(3!)!} =\frac{8!}{6!} = 8 \times 7 = 56 $$


Thank you! The problem looked a bit intimidating but I was able to follow along!

Just wondering have you found 77?

@user98205 just wondering: do you realise that the way to thank contributors here is to upvote their answers? When I ask a question, I upvote every answer that isn't complete rubbish.

I have a solution for 77 which bends the rules a little bit but doesn't necessarily break them.
In the link provided, the author allows for the arbitrary use of square roots and double factorial.
In particular

 If I apply the square root an infinite number of times to the value 2, I get 1. I write this as $$ \sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt{2}}} = 1$$

Then we have

 $$ \left( (4!!)!! + \sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt{2}}} \right) \times 0.2 =  77 $$


Here are the answers for 59 and 63:
59:

 $ \dfrac{4!}{2 \times .2} - 0! $

63:

 $ 2^{2 + 4} - 0! $


Thank you this is very helpful it’s nice to be able to understand the problems!

I'll work on the other 2, and update my answer

powers aren't on the allowed list though

On the given link, on the list of usable operations, it says that you can use exponentiation

On the other side, it says decimal digits can be placed between digits.

I see, well played

You can use those rules I just wasn’t sure about them at first.

can i use my previous answer for 59

Yep! all I need left is 77 now!

Hey any luck on 77?
